# Authentication proxy - req.user.sub persistent?

Tags: node.js, http, auth0

### Situation

I used the node.js quickstart project from auth0 to build an authentication-proxy. Reason for this is that I cannot merge my spring backend with the Quickstart spring example.

In order to let the spring backend identify the user, I pass the user's `sub` as shown below.

```
var authenticate = jwt({
    secret: new Buffer(process.env.AUTH0_CLIENT_SECRET, 'base64'),
    audience: process.env.AUTH0_CLIENT_ID
});

...

app.get('/secured/*', function (req, res) {
    var url = apiUrl + req.url;
    var userId = req.user.sub;   // 'auth0|muchoCrypto123'
    url += "?userId=" + userId;
    req.pipe(request(url)).pipe(res);
});
```

I am currently also investigating the usage of `HttpRequestServlet` in spring to retrieve user details.

### Question

Is `req.user.sub` a value that I can use to identify the user without worrying that this value might change? So far I couldn't detect changes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the user management console I found the following:

```
user_id               auth0|muchoCrypto123
```

Thus I assume that the `user_id` won't change. Can anyone confirm?

Comment: Hi @michaelbahr, did you ever get a confirmation on this?  This seem to be such a fundamental issue in Auth0, yet I can't find any documentation on this field.

Comment: I did not, sorry.